# Flutter inline boxes without wordwrap

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app with a menu at the bottom, this is the result:[image: current result]

I wrote the following code:

```
return Row(
  children: menuItems
      .asMap()
      .entries
      .map(
        (x) => Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: HGVColors.grey,
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => setTitle(x.key),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/${x.value.icon}.svg",
                    height: 25,
                    color: getColor(x.key == currentIndex),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    x.value.label,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: getColor(x.key == currentIndex),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
);
```

However, the desired result is followings:

[image]

What can I do in order that *Konventionen* is not wrapped to a new line, but stretches its container?

Comment: I would see if FittedBox could achieve what you want, either wrapping the Text widget with it or replacing the Container with it.

Comment: It works, the text is not wrapped anymore, but the font is reduced, the text is smaller.

Comment: I thikn you should use Expanded only for "Konventionen" and the rest just to use Container, so they would wrap, but  the Expanded would occupy  the left space.

Comment: @AlejandroCumpa Yes it works, but i don't think it is a nice solution...there must be a better way. If I rotate the phone, Konvention stretches and the others get to the minimum space.

Comment: Maybe using Flexible, instead of Expanded: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: HGVColors.grey,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: menuItems
            .asMap()
            .entries
            .map(
              (x) => InkWell(
                onTap: () => setTitle(x.key),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/images/${x.value.icon}.svg",
                      height: 25,
                      color: getColor(x.key == currentIndex),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      x.value.label,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: getColor(x.key == currentIndex),
                      ),                      
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
```

The key is `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`.